# jq: select object if certain value exists

Tags: kubernetes, jq

I have a list with multiple objects in an items list and try to select every item with an specific value inside an optional array in this object.
Let me explain by the actual problem:
I read all networkpolicies from a kubernetes namespace and try to output the names of all networkpilicies, which allow access to a certain IP address

The closest I cloud get is:

```
kubectl get netpol -ojson|jq -r '.items[]|select(.spec.egress[0].to[0].ipBlock.cidr=="1.2.3.4/32")|.metadata.name'
```

but this only works, if the ip block is the first one in the array. I have no idea, how to iterate over all elements in the array.
This

```
kubectl get netpol -ojson|jq -r '.items[]|select(.spec.egress[].to[].ipBlock.cidr=="1.2.3.4/32")|.metadata.name'
```

gives me an error `jq: error (at <stdin>:803): Cannot iterate over null (null)`

For reference, the egress block looks like this

```
    "egress": [
      {
        "ports": [
          {
            "port": 1234,
            "protocol": "TCP"
          }
        ],
        "to": [
          {
            "ipBlock": {
              "cidr": "1.2.3.4/32"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
```

Comment: jq is the new regex, but far worse :-(

Comment: if you could add a sample manifest, it would be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to be sure from your example since I don't know what was in your input data, but I believe the [egress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#networkpolicy-resource) field isn't guaranteed to be present. That would result in the error you see. You are also going to have trouble because when your select expression yields multiple results you will end up selecting the same item multiple times.

You might try the [any](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#any,any(condition),any(generator;condition)) function and the [.[]?](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#.%5B%5D%3F) operator:

```
.items[]|select(any(.spec.egress[]?.to[]?;.ipBlock.cidr=="1.2.3.4/32"))|.metadata.name
```

Comment: This works like a charm :) I wasn't aware of the []? in combination with any. Thank you so much